# How do I select a value from different tables in Query Builder Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-query-builder

So i'm trying to get "promo_type" value from mysql table to excel. However i need to use another table in order to get the value of this "promo_type".

So this is the main table booking, which contains the value of the promo code. Like shown below a user has a promo code of "1000".
Booking Table

[image]

Now in this other table, this is where the promo codes are made and saved.

Promo Code table

[image]

But i need to access the "promo_type" variable to be able to export it to excel. How can i do this? I was thinking of seleting the value of the promo code from the booking table and comparing it to the promo code table and then seleting the "promo_type" column. But i have no idea how to translate this to query builder syntax.

This is the code im using to export the data to excel. So i need to return it in a suitable way in order to export the value to excel.

```
public function collection()
{

    return Booking::select(
        'id',
        'place_id',
        'payer_name',
        'user_fullname',
        'user_email',
        'user_phone',
        'user_no_of_guest',
        'user_no_of_babies',
        'user_checkin',
        'user_checkout',
        'is_approved',
        'user_promo',
        'user_payment_type',
        'user_booking_tracking_id',
        'created_at',
        Booking::raw('(created_at +  INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AS created_at'),
        'paid_amount'
    )
        ->whereRaw('"' . $this->date . '" between `user_checkin` and `user_checkout`')
        ->get();
}



public function headings(): array
{
    return [
        'ID',
        'Place ID',
        'Payer Name',
        'Full Name',
        'Email',
        'Phone',
        'Number of adults',
        'Number of babies',
        'Arrival Time',
        'Checkout Time',
        'Approval',
        'Promo',
        'Payment Type',
        'Tracking Id',
        'Created At',
        'Total Amount',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code as text instead of an image?

Comment: yes sure sorry about that woild edit it now

Comment: Btw, you can improve your code by writing your `whereRaw()` like this: `->whereRaw('? between user_checkin and user_checkout', $this->date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use select for this, i would always use `Eloquent` approach. This is way more pragmatic and the expected way to do it.

You need to have a relationship to be able to do this, add `PromoCode` relationship to the `Booking.php` class.

```
class Booking
{
    public function promoCode()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PromoCode::class, 'user_promo', 'promocode');
    }
}
```

Now you can use the functions from `Laravel Excel` to query and map your data correctly.

```
public function collection()
{
    return Booking::whereRaw('"' . $this->date . + '" between `user_checkin` and `user_checkout`')->get();
}

public function map($booking): array
{
    return [
        // your other fields
        $booking->promoCode->promo_type,
    ];
}
```

Comment: For this question i assumed you used laravel excel since you had the public function collection() method

Comment: Yes i do, however i need to add the value of the promo type to the collection() function in order for it to appear to excel i assume, how can i do this? Thanks for the help btw

Comment: I'm stil not able to get this. If you notice in my code above, in the colection function, im returning a value called 'user_promo' which is in the Booking database. However i need to change that to 'promo_type' which is in the Promo Database. Not sure exactly how i can do this with the example you provided.

Comment: You are doing that in the map, the map transforms each model to a row in excel, there you can see i fetch the promo_type on the promo code. The collection returns models, with the relationship the model can fetch a promoCode like so $booking->promoCode, i think for you it would be good to read up on relationships in Laravel, because if you struggle with knowing how to get promo_type, maybe that subject matter is lacking. And that is quite an important part of laravel :)

Comment: The issue here is that i have a heading function aswell, do i just get rid of the heading function, i edited the post again so you can take a look at it.

Comment: No the heading function describes the header and the map transforms each row, so array position 0 in the map will be column 1 in excel.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your table relation. Based your concept, instead of using `promo_code` column, you should add a `promo_code_id` column that have reference to `id` in Promo Code table (foreign key).

In your model, you can utilize an Eloquent `hasOne()` relationship to Booking model such as

```php
class Booking extends Model
{
    public function promoCode()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PromoCode::class, 'id', 'promo_code_id');
    }

    ...

}
```

PromoCode is a model for the Promo Code table.

Then, you can get the Promo Code data by using Eloquent relation

```php
public function foo()
{
    $promoCode = Booking::first()->promoCode;
}
```